Comparing the norm map of ramified quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$ and of $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p$
Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Let $E$ be a ramified quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ with non-trivial Galois involution denoted by $a \mapsto \overline{a}$. Let us fix a uniformizer $\pi \in E$ such that $\overline{\pi} = - \pi$. Note that in particular, $\pi_0 := \pi^2$ is a uniformizer in $\mathbb Q_p$. We have $E = \mathbb Q_p[\pi]$. Let $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p := \mathrm{Frac}(W(\overline{\mathbb F_p}))$ be the fraction field of the ring of Witt vectors of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$. Then $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p$ is also the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$. The tensor product $\breve E := E \otimes_{\mathbb Q_p} \breve{\mathbb Q}_p$ is a field. In fact, $\breve E$ is a ramified quadratic extension of $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p$ and we have $\breve E = \breve{\mathbb Q}_p[\pi]$. We still write $a\mapsto \overline{a}$ for the non-trivial Galois involution relative to $\breve E / \breve{\mathbb Q}_p$.
Let $N$ (resp. $\breve N$) denote the norm map relative to the quadratic extension $E/\mathbb Q_p$ (resp. $\breve E/ \breve{\mathbb Q}_p$). By definition, we have $N(a) = a\overline{a}$ for all $a\in E$ (and similarly for $\breve N$). Of course, the restriction of $\breve N$ to $E \subset \breve E$ coincides with $N$.

Let $\delta \in \breve E$ such that $\breve N(\delta) = \delta\overline{\delta}$ actually belongs to $\mathbb Q_p \subset \breve{\mathbb Q}_p$. Is there necessarily a $\delta' \in E$ such that $\breve N(\delta) = N(\delta')$ ?

In other words, observing that $N(x + \pi y) = x^2 - \pi^2y^2$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb Q_p$ (and similarly for $\breve N$), the question can be rephrased as follows:

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb Q_p$. If the quadratic form $x^2 - \pi^2y^2$ represents $\lambda$ over $\breve{\mathbb Q}_p$, does it also represent $\lambda$ over $\mathbb Q_p$ ?


No. Let $x \in \mathbb F_p^\times \setminus (\mathbb F_p^\times)^2$, and let $\tau: \overline{\mathbb F_p} \rightarrow W(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$ be the Teichmüller map.
$\tau(x) \in \mathbb Q_p$ (it is the element of $\mu_{p-1}$ which is $\equiv x \pmod{p}$), but it is not in the image of the norm map of either of the two ramified quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$: because that image (except $0$) is a multiplicative subgroup generated by the principal units $(1+p\mathbb Z_p)$, the squares in $\mu_{p-1}$, and the uniformizer $\pi^2$, so if it also contained $\tau(x)$ it would be all of $\mathbb Q_p$.
But $\tau(x)$ is a square in  $W(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$, so it's in the image of the norm map of any quadratic extension of the fraction field of this ring.

More generally: You are asking if $im(\breve{N}) \cap \mathbb Q_p \subseteq im(N)$. But the image of the norm map $N$ (away from $0$) is known very explicitly as subgroup of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Q_p$ (that's the start point of Kummer theory and class field theory), and you can even imitate that for $\breve{N}$. Noting that the first (and really, only) difference occurs in the torsion part i.e. the roots of unity led me to the counterexample.

Thank you Torsten for this counter example. I'm totally convinced.
